Does papaparse 5.0.2 remove downloadRequestBody?
downloadRequestBody isn't working and I can find no reference to it in the full JS.
The one XMLHttpRequest xhr this I find is in _readChunk
xhr.open('GET', this._input, !IS_WORKER);
// Headers can only be set when once the request state is OPENED
if (this._config.downloadRequestHeaders)
{
    var headers = this._config.downloadRequestHeaders;

    for (var headerName in headers)
{
    xhr.setRequestHeader(headerName, headers[headerName]);
}
}

if (this._config.chunkSize)
{
    var end = this._start + this._config.chunkSize - 1; // minus one because byte range is inclusive
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=' + this._start + '-' + end);
}

try {
    xhr.send();
}
catch (err) {
    this._chunkError(err.message);
}

I tried
var url = reportBaseUrl;
var postBody = "src=" + report.src +
"&agg=" + encodeURIComponent(PBIReports.SelectedReport) +
   "&json=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(PBIReports.Filters));/* */

Papa.parse(url, {
    download: true,
      downloadRequestBody: postBody,
      downloadRequestHeaders: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },

and expected the receiver to get a POST but it got a GET after which I cracked the file looking for POST support.
It was pretty easy to edit the JS.
var method = this._config.downloadRequestBody ? 'POST' : 'GET';

if (!this._config.downloadRequestBody) {
    this._config.downloadRequestBody = null;
}

xhr.open(method, this._input, !IS_WORKER);

...
xhr.send(this._config.downloadRequestBody);
